# Odoo doesn't displays markdown images

Tags: python, odoo

I want to display a markdown(readme) file into an odoo view as a field, i'm using the parser mistune to parse the file into an html format; as a result, the text is displayed as expected, except for every images located in `src/img` folder for the odoo module structure.
(example of image: `![Capture](static/src/img/usecase.png)`)

I've tried with the html inspector and it says the image wasn't found, and when I hover it, the path is `http://server-s551lb:8069/static/src/img/usecase.png` and I find it weird because it's only the relative path to locate the image.
Any help or idea would be welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

I've found by adding `modulename/` before static from the relative path of the image :)